# Function to capitalize first three letters on each word within given array

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that takes in a single word and capitalizes the first three letters. Now I need to run this same function on an array of words, so that it returns each word with the first three letters capitalized. I see there's a lot of people asking how to capitalize the first letter on each word of a sentence, but this is not the same thing. I have to use the function I already wrote so when I console.log it it looks like this:

```
console.log(applyAll(['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'], capitalizeThreeLetters));
```

I tried doing this using a for loop which returns every word together. In my research I saw the forEach() method could be used to run a function on array elements but I cannot figure out how to apply it.

```
//Function that takes in str returns it with three first letters capitalized

function capitalizeThreeLetters(str){

  let capFirst = str[0].toUpperCase();
  let capSecond = str[1].toUpperCase();
  let capThird = str[2].toUpperCase();

  let splitStr = str.slice(3);

  let wholeStr = capFirst + capSecond + capThird + splitStr;
  return wholeStr;
}

console.log(capitalizeThreeLetters('testing')); // => returns 'TESting'
console.log(capitalizeThreeLetters('again')); // => returns 'AGAin'



//Function that takes in a string array and applies capitalizeThreeLetters function to each array element so each word is returned with first three letters capitalized

function applyAll(arr){
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  return capitalizeThreeLetters(arr);
  }
}  

console.log(applyAll(['mai', 'brian', 'jeho', 'han'], capitalizeThreeLetters)); 
// => returns 'MAIBRIANJEHOhan'
// => should return ['MAI', 'BRIan', 'JEHo', 'HAN']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `applyAll` function doesn't work the way you want. When you `return` the function immediately exits. In this case, you return inside the loop thus prevent the loop from continuing and running the other 2 iterations.

Your second issue is that you pass the entire array to `capitalizeThreeLetters` instead of a single word. You probably want `capitalizeThreeLetters(arr[i])`. Right now, you are passing the entire array in which leads to the first 3 *words* in the array being capitalized instead of the first 3 letters of each word.

You can fix it using `map`:

```js
function applyAll(arr){
  return arr.map(capitalizeThreeLetters);
}
```

The [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) on an array will call a function on each element of the array then return a new array with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get a new array with the modified values of a current one

```js
//Function that takes in str returns it with three first letters capitalized

function capitalizeThreeLetters(str){

  let capFirst = str[0].toUpperCase();
  let capSecond = str[1].toUpperCase();
  let capThird = str[2].toUpperCase();

  let splitStr = str.slice(3);

  let wholeStr = capFirst + capSecond + capThird + splitStr;
  return wholeStr;
}

const result = ['mai', 'brian', 'jeho', 'han'].map(capitalizeThreeLetters);

console.log(result);
```

There's no need to convert each `[0] [1]` etc characters to uppercase, you can use `.toUppercase()` on the sliced portion.
Also you can parametrize the number of characters to capitalize:

```js
const capitalize = (str, tot=1) => str.slice(0, tot).toUpperCase() + str.slice(tot);

const result = ['mai', 'brian', 'jeho', 'han'].map((str) => capitalize(str, 3));
console.log(result);
```